# Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined - yet jQuery is loaded and script works

Tags: jquery, wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin

Anybody have a clue as to why I am getting an 'Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined' error, yet jquery is loaded and the script actually does what it supposed to (i.e works).

I am using the Gravity Forms hook gform_confirmation to create and run a script...

```
<script>jQuery(document).bind(\'gform_confirmation_loaded\',function(){alert(\'Here is the file\')});</script>
```

Even though I get the error the script still works.  I am trying to figure out why.

Anybody have any thoughts?

Comment: Maybe you are loading jquery more than once...or maybe you have some jquery code before the inclusion of the jquery library...

Comment: I was thinking that perhaps the code is fired before jQuery is included.  But I was under the impression that WordPress loads jQuery in the header.  Then again this part of Gravity Forms is via AJAX so maybe it's is messing with the order of the inclusion.